# How to distinct rows with multiple conditions on multiple rows using spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here's my df:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| a  |  b |  c |  d |
+----+----+----+----+
  zz   ss    0    1 
+----+----+----+----+
  zz   ss    0    0
+----+----+----+----+
  qs   qs    1    1
+----+----+----+----+
```

I want to obtain：

```
+----+----+----+----+
| a  |  b |  c |  d |
+----+----+----+----+
  zz   ss    0    1 
+----+----+----+----+
  qs   qs    1    1
+----+----+----+----+
```

Since I want to distinct rows on cols `a` and `b`, and filter the row with only `d==1`.
However, it's possible that one rows fit both `c` and `d` equals to 0, and these rows are distinct on `a` and `b` already, which are not supposed to be filtered out.
The condition `d==1` is used only when there're duplicated rows (same `a` and `b` values) for de-duplicating.

Comment: So you want to ignore rows for each `(a, b)` having _both_ `c` and `d` values of zero?  Or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I want to distinct rows on `a` and `b`, with condition that keeps `d==1` and discards the rest (duplicate rows).

Comment: `SELECT a, b, c, d FROM yourTable WHERE d = 1` should do it (I think)

Comment: No, the others non-duplicated rows with `d=0` are needed. The condition `d==1` is used only for duplicated rows.

Comment: Maybe add more robust sample data which covers all edge cases.  I can't say that I see what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `a` and `b`, collect the columns `c` and `d` into an array, sort the array so that elements with `d` = 1 are ordered first and then take the first element of the array.

```python
df.groupBy("a", "b").agg(F.collect_set(F.struct("c","d")).alias("data")) \
  .withColumn("data", F.expr("array_sort(data, (l, r) -> if(l.d = 1,-1,if(r.d=1, 1 ,0)))[0]")) \
  .select("a", "b", "data.c", "data.d") \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
| zz| ss|  0|  1|
| qs| qs|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

As [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) has already said in the comments, there are some corner cases left which you should handle inside of the `if` function